# "Focus on Flavor" Column

Tags: flavor, off-flavor, taste, judging

I am trying to locate copies of a *complete set* of Scott Bickham's "Focus on Flavors" column in Brewing Techniques, which seems like it was a journal or magazine in the 1990s.

The question is can anyone help me determine the full list of articles in the column, and to locate copies of the articles? Finding them online would be great, but I would be happy to pay for back issues.

It seems that the series included at last the following, and I have linked to the ones I have located:

- [An Introduction to Sensory Analysis, 12/97](http://morebeer.com/brewingtechniques/library/backissues/issue5.6/bickham.html)
- Four Basic Tastes and Beer Doctoring Trials, 1/98, [back issue available here](http://morebeer.com/products/volume-6-1.html)
- Staving off Staling, 3/98. [back issue available here](http://morebeer.com/products/volume-6-2.html)
- [Sulfur Struck - Sources and Impact of Sulfur Compounds in Beer, 5/98](http://morebeer.com/articles/sulfur_compounds_in_beer)
- [Fatty Flavors and Diacetyl, 7/98](http://api.ning.com/files/yIAsUA%2aNK%2aS2GbcUpcOIyNRyUbZKBC9rnun3HZQzU8JramMMOVOJFIwThbTg8j-jmkCScBwE3r6hTgrzHk5EqF85P7Uj1IZl/FattyFlavorsandDiacetyl.PDF)
- [Flavors from Malt, 9/98](http://morebeer.com/articles/malt_flavors)
- [Hoppy and Maturation Flavors in a Nutshell, 11/98](http://api.ning.com/files/WPIPonkHYLlTIJIOeASI1iKMRM-5YEJKxHmjX4AaIQEWIYAEUhfIiUCMPkyPibJNHJvW7udms8gBy8ZXlFRaxTkKIWjbZTND/HoppyandMaturationFlavors.PDF)
- [Flavors from Esters and Alcohols, 5/99](http://api.ning.com/files/0WTnUQYNZ4GQ2eXYtCEHPfMSSZB4DaoQ8SbVvVTG6Et%2aHQkem8us6r-izTENYlMDw1ci4yI5nwbsc-XNh1jzIxAXyZSccqYn/FlavorsfromEstersandAlcohols.PDF)

Hopefully, this is not off-topic.

Comment: This is the quintessential question for something like Stack Exchange in my humble opinion.  Might even do well as a community wiki.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to answer this question myself, based on additional research. The list of columns in the question is complete. Also, the question has been edited to provide links for a source for each column. I will note that the Focus on Flavor column is often cited as a good study resource for the BJCP exam.